# Solution to non-homogenous second-order differential equation from Navier-Stokes equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was using the simplified Navier-Stokes equations to find the velocity profile within a cylindrical pipe, where I got the equation as:

$ \alpha = \frac{\partial V^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$

I understand this is a second-order differential equation but am unable to derive the solution which is stated as:

$V= \frac{\alpha r^2}{4}+Aln(r)+B$

where $A$ and $B$ are some constants.

Usually, if there is a number in place of $1/r$, I understand how to find a general solution by using the quadratic method and then finding a particular solution, however, this is a variable? Any ideas on how to approach this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \alpha = \frac{\partial V^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$$
Multiply both sides by $r$
$$rV''+V'=\alpha r$$
$$\implies (rV')'=\alpha r$$
Integrate
$$\implies (rV')=\alpha \frac {r^2}2 +c_1$$
It's a first order DE now. 
$$\implies V'=\alpha \frac {r}2 +\frac {c_1} r$$
Integrate again
$$\implies V=\alpha \frac {r^2}4 +c_1 \ln r+c_2$$

Comment: Thank you. How did you go from:

$rV''+V'=\alpha r$

to

$(rV')'=\alpha r$

Comment: If you dont understand that step try to go from step 3 to step 2 Asif Differentiate $(rV')$

Comment: Ahhhh thank you so much !!!!!!!

Comment: You welcome Asif... I just differentiated $(rV')$

Comment: You can also substitute $Z=V'$ and $Z'=V''$ and treat that equation as a  first order DE and then use whatever method you like. For example integrating factor..